# How to reject not valid value from List in Spring validator?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I receive list of domain object ids deserialized from `JSON` client request body:

```
@JsonProperty("workgroups")
private List<WorkgroupId> workgroupIds = new ArrayList<>();
```

I need to validate these ids in `org.springframework.validation.Validator`.

```
for (WorkgroupId workgroupId : project.getWorkgroupIds()) {
  if (!domainObjectTools.doesWorkgroupExist(workgroupId)) {
// reject this invalid value here...
  }
}
```

**Question**

How to reject invalid value in `org.springframework.validation.Errors`?

Answer (score -1):

Validator interface:

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { CustomValidatorValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface CustomValidator{
    String message() default "Put here your default message";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

ValidatorImplementation:

```
public final class CustomValidatorValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomValidator, List<WorkgroupId>> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(CustomValidator constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<WorkgroupId> yourlist, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (yourlist== null)
            return true;
        else
            return yourlist.stream().anyMatch(s -> /* filter here as you want */);
    }
}
```

Notice we return `true` if the field is null, I do it like this because I just put `@NotNull` constraint if I need not to be null so I have more control over the constraint.

Finally:

```
@JsonProperty("workgroups")
@CustomValidator
private List<WorkgroupId> workgroupIds = new ArrayList<>();
```

P.S: I don't understand why you initialize the list in this last code. If that's a field you're supposed to receive through the request then you don't need to initialize it, the json deserializer will initialize it with the incoming field in the json.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **reject()** and/or **rejectValue()** along with the field/error code/defaultMessage or along with a custom validator to reject the values.